# Importing GeoJSON into PostGIS with Python

Tags: python, postgis, geojson

I am trying to import GeoJSON file with Python to my PostgreSQL db.

Here is full code:

```
with open('C:/xampp/htdocs/app/data/'+a) as file:
    gj=geojson.load(file)
    for feature in gj['features']:
        geom=feature['geometry']
        kc_broj=feature['properties']['BROJ_KC']
        ko_broj=feature['properties']['KO']
        ko_naziv=feature['properties']['K.O.']
        jls='RUGVICA1'
        id=str(ko_broj)+'_'+kc_broj
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO dkp (id,geom,ko_broj,kc_broj,ko_naziv,jls) VALUES (%s, ST_GeomFromText(ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(%s))), %s, %s, %s, %s)', (id, geom ,ko_broj, kc_broj, ko_naziv, jls,))
```

And I get error :

psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'Polygon'

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: In the insert command some apostrophes missing. Print your Insert command from Python and try to execute in psql or pgadmin.

Comment: @Zoltan can you underline where apostrophes are missing because when I copy this command into sql command window it works fine

Comment: If it works from the SQL prompt then my assumption was false.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Insert statement seems OK. But you could try to replace this line:

```
geom=feature['geometry']
```

with

```
geom = (json.dumps(feature['geometry']))))
```

Because feature['geometry'] is an object and you should convert it to json.

And in insert statement you should set SRID for geometry if you have constraint in PostGIS. Like this:

```
ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(%s), 4326)
```